# Include a link in an email to document(s) in a SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform

I have the following list and document library in the same SharePoint site:

`SharePoint List` (Policy Inventory):

[image]

`SharePoint Document Library` (Policy-Working-Documents):
[image: Sharepoint Document Library]

My current flow filters for items in the list with a `review date` that is +120 days from today, then it gets the files from the document library sub-folder named `Test-Folder`.

I am really struggling with the following:

1. Filtering the `Get Files` output so as to keep only the files with a `Name` that is also contained in the output of `Get Items`?
2. Send an `Outlook` email that contains the documents from #1 as an attachment or link. The body of the email should include the `Document Name` and `Review Date` which are provided in the `Policy Inventory` list.

My current flow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `Get Files`, `Create HTML Table` and `Send an Email` to achieve what was asked in the title:

First the Get Files and Create HTML Table -> the value in `From` is the collection received from the Get Files step
[image]

Then the final Send an Email step uses the output as the Body from the Create HTML Table step:
[image]

EDIT:
To filter the OData `Get Files` step use the following steps - `Get Items` from the list with file name filters
[image]

Then `Initialize String Variable` for the OData filter, append to that variable the following:
concat('or FileLeafRef eq', '''', items('Apply_to_each_3')?['Title'], '''')
[image]

That'll create the OData filter and use that in the `Get Files` step `Advanced` and `Filter Query` value.

Comment: Is there a way to filter the `Get Files` for files that have names that are contained in the `Get Items` output?

Comment: @iamericfletcher that comment was incorrect, powerautomate doesn't support several operators such as IN or Contains, one of the solutions is to get all the items and then filter on them, the solution suggested here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-Items-OData-filter-contains-is-invalid/m-p/634463/highlight/true#M84485

Comment: I followed the link and tried implementing the solution but it's throwing an error. I used `Filter array` with `from` being the value from `Get files` and `Title column` from the document library and `Document name` from the `Get items` output. 


Here is a link to flow with attempted implementation of solution:

[https://imgur.com/gallery/6ETHV7N](https://imgur.com/gallery/6ETHV7N)

Comment: @iamericfletcher check the edit, specified how to build the OData filter query from the Get Items and then use it in Get Files